# OneTime Setup Screen Android Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android development and trying to make an app where a screen is showing first time and asking user to set an password and after the password is set ,that screen is never shown again .
I wrote a basic code implementing this,but when running my app on an emulator ,the same setup screen is shown again and again.Can anybody point out the reason for this?

Code:

```
    package com.example.homeautomation.zigbeehomeauto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class SetupScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
View v ;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        SharedPreferences check = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean hasLoggedIn = check.getBoolean("Name", false);


        if (hasLoggedIn) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(SetupScreen.this, MainScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
        else {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup_screen);

        }


    }

        public void Send(View v) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();


        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String value = text.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("Name", "value");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(SetupScreen.this, MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();


    }
    }
```

Comment: Check error in logcat and post here.

Comment: did you mention your activity in the manifest file ?

Comment: You should show the screen first, save the information about in in persistent storage e,g shared preferences and while loading the home screen, check whether you have already done that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some function calls can not be made until the activity is initiated, you can call getSharedPreferences() over there, instead call in onCreate();
Or if you want that value every time use in onResume();

```
SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
protected void onResume() //or in onCreate() as per your needs
{
    super.onResume();
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: i edited the code thanks , application now runs but have an issue that welcome screen is shown every time when i run it in emulator.

Comment: You are not setting content view at all. Than whats the problem? Does it shows white scree you say?

Comment: the previous problem has been resolved but in new code , the setup screen should be shown only once but it is been shown on every start of application.

Comment: Here you cant just add new questions, this was the answer for old question, rather edit your question. Activity will be shown as it will be your launcher activity as per menifest, what you can do is apply NoTitleBar theme to setup activity so it will show only white screen.